# Create a dictionary with variable number of keys and variable number of for loops

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, recursion, nested

I have already written code in this way:

```
base_points = [ {'cHW':value1, 'cHWtil':value2} for value1 in [-1.5, -.8]  for value2 in [-1.5, -.8]]
```

The output is just a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'cHW': -1.5, 'cHWtil': -1.5},
 {'cHW': -1.5, 'cHWtil': -0.8},
 {'cHW': -0.8, 'cHWtil': -1.5},
 {'cHW': -0.8, 'cHWtil': -0.8}]
```

But what I want to do now is have a number of keys as variable.
This means I also need a variable number of for loops.
I thought of solving this recursively. I can implement the variable number for loop like that in a simple way. But I am not sure how to implement the varying number of keys.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Use 2 normal for loops instead of list comprehension.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve and what problem you cannot solve

Comment: something like `{k: v for k,v in zip('abcdefghij', range(10)}`? this results in `{'a':0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, ..., j: 9}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what I believe your question is asking:

```py
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
values = [-1.5, -.8]
from itertools import product
base_points = [{keys[i]:combo[i] for i in range(len(keys))} for combo in product(values, repeat=len(keys))]
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': -1.5, 'key2': -1.5, 'key3': -1.5},
 {'key1': -1.5, 'key2': -1.5, 'key3': -0.8},
 {'key1': -1.5, 'key2': -0.8, 'key3': -1.5},
 {'key1': -1.5, 'key2': -0.8, 'key3': -0.8},
 {'key1': -0.8, 'key2': -1.5, 'key3': -1.5},
 {'key1': -0.8, 'key2': -1.5, 'key3': -0.8},
 {'key1': -0.8, 'key2': -0.8, 'key3': -1.5},
 {'key1': -0.8, 'key2': -0.8, 'key3': -0.8}]
```

Explanation:

- The variables `keys` and `values` are lists of arbitrary length
- [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) provides nested for-loop behavior to cycle through the items in `values` at each key position so that a separate dictionary can be created for each possible combination of values at each key position

Comment: wow that's really compact! thanks.